# I would like to know what DBMS options do I have when I sell my software

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have created a billing / inventory management software for a client in VB.net. Right now I am using an MS Access database (accdb) for data storage.

I had to manually define Triggers in VB code for it (I don't want to do this all the time, hence the question). I know that MySQL and MS SQL Servers do support Database triggers. But to distribute them with my paid software, I will need a commercial license. Are there any free alternatives, that I can package with my installer?

Right now I have only sold the VB.net program. The customer already has Office 2007.

Should I continue to sell my programs this way? Or is there an easier alternative which  I can package with the installer? I don't want to code for functionality that is already present in a DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) is free for redistribution with your application.

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/) is open source and is also free for redistribution with your application.